# Move the position of menu item

Tags: css

**What is happening?** The third level menu overlap to the dropdown menu.

[image: Third level menu]

**Goal?** The third level menu should outsite the dropdown menu.

[image: Goal: Third level menu]

**What have I tried so far?** I just added inline css to the second menu level in Web-Developer-Modus in Browser.

```
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu" style="display: none; left: 11rem; top: -0.5rem; width: min-content;">
    <li id="menu-item-400" class="nav-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-400 open"><a title="Öffentlichkeitsarbeit" href="http://localhost:38080/oeffentlichkeitsarbeit" class="dropdown-item">Öffentlichkeitsarbeit</a></li>
</ul>
```

> ```
> left: 11rem; top: -0.5rem; width: min-content;
> ```

**How can I change the javascript to add a the css class .open only for the menu in the second level? Or is a solution in [wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php](https://gitlab.com/foodsharing-dev/ag-bezirkswebsite/foodsharing-wordpress-bezirks-website/blob/demo/foodsharing-bezirks-website/inc/wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php) better?**

```
jQuery(function($) {
if($(window).width()>769){
    $('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(250).slideDown();

    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp();

    });

    $('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function(){
        location.href = this.href;
    });

} });
```

---

- [Gitlab-Repo](https://gitlab.com/foodsharing-dev/ag-bezirkswebsite/foodsharing-wordpress-bezirks-website)
- [Gitlab Issue](https://gitlab.com/foodsharing-dev/ag-bezirkswebsite/foodsharing-wordpress-bezirks-website/issues/22)
- [Demo-Page](https://wp-style-demo.fs-bezirk.de/)
- [Question before: Page from parentmenu is not opening](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/344820/page-from-parent-menu-is-not-opening)

Comment: This seems mostly a CSS issue, and thus off topic, please consult the [help] to get familiar with the site guidelines. The nav menu walker class has the depth parameter for several of its methods available, which you can use to add classes by level, depth. The open class is afaik added by bootstrap js, not by the walker class though. As a third-party library bootstrap is off topic too.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: `#main-nav ul li ul ul {
    margin-left: 150px;
    width: 250px;
}`